# Restringir acesso a uma pasta no servidor após sessão iniciada

Tags: php, session, login

Estou com o seguinte problema: Tenho 1 aplicação utilizada por 5 usuarios...

Para cada usuário existe uma pasta no servidor, pois para cada um existe uma configuração e alguns arquivos são diferentes, sendo assim os links de autenticação ficam:

> user1 = www.meuservidor.com.br/pasta1
>   user2 = www.meuservidor.com.br/pasta2
>   user3 = www.meuservidor.com.br/pasta3
>   user4 = www.meuservidor.com.br/pasta4
>   user5 = www.meuservidor.com.br/pasta5

Na `index` de cada pasta, tem uma tela de login que faz via ajax a autenticação no banco do login e senha passados pelo usuário, com a seguintes condições:

```
//Caso o usuário não esteja autenticado, abre tela de login
if ( !isset($_SESSION['login']) and !isset($_SESSION['senha']) ) {
    //exibe form de login
}else{
    //exibe a pagina restrita
}
```

**Situação de Exemplo:**

Se eu me logo no user1...minha sessão é iniciada normalmente, mas se eu modificar a url eu consigo acessar a index das outras pastas...pois a sessão já foi iniciada.

Preciso de ajuda para bloquear isso.

Comment: Faça um arquivo index central que inclua os outros arquivos para navegação e uma validação da url para cada tipo de usuário antes de exibir a pasta, caso for /pasta1 e user2 redireciona pra /pasta2 sem deixar abrir a /pasta1

Comment: Charles Fay, na hora que o usuário loga guarde mais um elemento na sessão que é a pasta ... Na hora que o usuário entrar em pasta diferente você tem mais essa regra para restringir o acesso, apesar que o sua regra de negócio está completamente enganada ao meu ver, porque, deveria ter somente só um login e o mesmo ter a decisões dos usuários.

Comment: Repense mais sobre o seu sistema e sua lógica de processo, porque o problema é se aumentar o numero de usuários, pode ser desastroso ...

Comment: Bem colocada a sugestão do @Cezar, oque tem nessas pastas? o que o usuário vê? o ideal seria criar um login só e uma pasta só, determinando o que cada usuário pode ver a partir de regras.

Comment: Então, na verdade isso não iria funcionar para o meu caso, pois para cada pasta tem um script php, com parametros e arquivos diferentes...o usuário vê o resultado processado pelos arquivos php contidos dentro da pasta dele

Comment: @Mastria, os mesmos arquivos que tem em uma pasta tem também na outra, no entanto não são dinâmicos...pois achei melhor assim. Mas se não tiver jeito vou ter que mudar tudo.

Comment: Isso só te vai dar trabalho, o melhor seria definires os privilégios durante o login, mas deixando a configuração de administração num diretório único, restringindo apenas os menus, e opções.

Comment: A estrutura em geral está errada, conforme comentaram. Eu apenas reforço os avisos. Procure montar uma estrutura melhor pois está criando um monstro que lhe dará dor de cabeça. Esse problema da lógica com login é fruto do que criaste e, é o menor dos problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, de acordo com o que você passou, o indicado seria criar uma regra dentro de cada arquivo php que está em cada pasta (um tanto repetitivo, e menos prático, mas atende sua regra):

Dentro de cada arquivo, faça a regra se não está logado redireciona para a tela /login, exemplo:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) and !isset($_SESSION['senha']) ) {
    header('Location: ./login'); // ou a forma como desejar redirecionar
}
```

Faça também a verificação do usuário para cada pasta, ficando:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) and !isset($_SESSION['senha']) ) {
    header('Location: ./login'); // ou a forma como desejar redirecionar
} else if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] != 1) { // digamos que estamos no arquivo da pasta1, guarde o tipo do usuario ao realizar login
   header('Location: ./pasta'.$_SESSION['tipo_usuario']); // concatena o nome da pasta pra jogar para a pasta do usuário correspondente
}
```

E no login (único) faça mesma coisa pra redirecionar ao fizer login:

```
header('Location: ./pasta'.$_SESSION['tipo_usuario']);
```

Essa é uma das formas para sua aplicação, espero que ajude.

Abraços

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Eu entendo que é menos prático, mas como essa é uma aplicação para um caso bem específico do meu cliente, essa forma serve perfeitamente.

Comment: Caso se complique com erros de "Cannot modify header information", peça para o @Maestria explicar o por que do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade fiz assim:

Mas os créditos são para o @Mastria

```
$user = $_SESSION['login'];

//Caso o usuário não esteja autenticado, abre tela de login
if ( !isset($_SESSION['login']) and !isset($_SESSION['senha']) ) {
    //exibe form de login
}else{
    if($user == 'user1'){
        //exibe a pagina restrita
    }else{
        echo "Acesso negado!";
    }        
}
```

Implementei esse código na index de cada usuário...
Como são apenas 5 não deu tanto trabalho, mas entendo que caso venha aumentar o numero de usuários terei que reformular a lógica da aplicação.

Obrigado a todos que participaram!

Comment: Uma dica é não ficar guardando em sessão a senha do usuário, não vejo necessidade. Veja que antes de verificar se a sessão login existe você já atribuiu ela a variável `$user` isso pode gerar um erro também. Abraço